# How to fix error "Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible"

Tags: typescript, react-native

I recently passed my react native project to typescript and i have this error and i don't find how to fix it.
The error is :
`Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible`
[image]

This is the authentication reducer :

```
const initialState = {
  credentials: {
    Username: '',
    Password: '',
  },
  LoggedIn: false,
};

function authentication(state = initialState, action: any) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        credentials: action.credentials,
      };
    case userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { state };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default authentication;
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: try remove case userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST: return { credentials: action.credentials ,}; then the error should be gone

Comment: But i need this case and if i remove it it don't change anything

Comment: try to make so the acthentication function only return type {credentials: {Username : string, Password : string}; LoggedIn : boolean} or undefined, is the error gone?

Comment: When i do what you say i get this error'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. [2693]

Comment: If you need more detail ask me ^^

Comment: replace string with a variable or ''

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Can you give me the code with the modification or be more clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187770/discussion-between-michel-melhem-and-davidloper).

Comment: Have you found a workable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about the signature of `ActionReducer`.

```
export interface ActionReducer<T, V extends Action = Action> {
    (state: T | undefined, action: V): T;
}
```

As you can see it is either `T` or `undefined`. However in your reducer, state is probably defined as `T` only. And that causes a type issue.

Comment: Thanks, the error came out, but there is a warning that says  'ActionReducer' is declared but its value is never read